# How to Distinguish between ID values of html Element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually I have two divs available on my page with buttons and I am passing the hidden field attached with that button to the jquery function But when I click on the second div it pass the value of the first div. Below is the html code

```
<div id="polls-42-ans"class="wp-polls-ans">
   <input type="button" name="vote" value="Vote" class="Buttons" id="vote-btn">
   <input type="hidden" value="42" id="poll-id"> 
</div>

<div id="polls-11-ans"class="wp-polls-ans">
   <input type="button" name="vote" value="Vote" class="Buttons" id="vote-btn">
   <input type="hidden" value="11" id="poll-id"> 
</div>
```

And I am using this jquery :

```
$(document).on('click','#vote-btn', function() {
  console.log( $("#poll-id").val()); 
});
```

NOTE: The Div ids are not same all the time

Comment: IDs must be unique `id="poll-id"`

Comment: You have elements with the same id, that's the problem: it's invalid HTML and entirely foreseeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` attribute should be unique in the same document, it will be better if you're using global classes instead :

```
<div id="polls-42-ans"class="wp-polls-ans">
  <input type="button" name="vote" value="Vote" class="Buttons vote-btn">
  <input type="hidden" value="42" class="poll-id"> 
</div>

<div id="polls-11-ans"class="wp-polls-ans">
  <input type="button" name="vote" value="Vote" class="Buttons vote-btn">
  <input type="hidden" value="11" class="poll-id"> 
</div>
```

Then use **[`siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** to target the related field :

```
$(this).siblings(".poll-id").val();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).on('click','.vote-btn', function() {
  console.log( $(this).siblings(".poll-id").val() ); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="polls-42-ans"class="wp-polls-ans">
  <input type="button" name="vote" value="Vote" class="Buttons vote-btn">
  <input type="hidden" value="42" class="poll-id"> 
</div>

<div id="polls-11-ans"class="wp-polls-ans">
  <input type="button" name="vote" value="Vote" class="Buttons vote-btn">
  <input type="hidden" value="11" class="poll-id"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working javascript code:

```
$(document).on('click','#vote-btn', function() {
  console.log( $(this).siblings("#poll-id").val() ); 
});
```

Comment: Add more explanation about the code to give a better understanding of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the DIVs with the class "wp-polls-ans" and then the buttons inside

```
 $(".wp-polls-ans #vote-btn").click(function(){
     var val =  $(this).parent().find( "#poll-id").val();
     alert(val);
   })
```

[This is the fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/9y7amd31/)